# Replace placeholder in ListFragment item by new Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragment with list of categories. Item in this list is layout like below. I need onclick on element of this list to show subcategories by replacing placeholder with a new instance of CategoryListFragment. How to use FragmentManager to replace in that scenerio ?

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_item_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/category_item_name"
        android:id="@+id/subcategories_fragment_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment

```
public class CategoryListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {

    public static CategoryListFragment create(Category parent) {
         CategoryListFragment f = new CategoryListFragment();
         ...
         return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        FrameLayout placeholder = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.subcategories_fragment_placeholder);
        CategoryListFragment subs = CategoryListFragment.create(adapter.getItem(position));

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()...
        // ???
    }

}
```

Comment: `getActivity().getFragmentManager()`?

Comment: I'm using nested fragments so `getChildFragmentManager()` is ok i think, but i don't know what next - how to use placeholder in it.

Comment: `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(v.getId,new CategoryListFragment());`. If your adapter is not setting an id to each row do it youself by calling `view.setId(View.generateViewId())`

Comment: Thank You :) I didn't know about `view.setId(View.generateViewId())`